# Как реализовать парсер на php для js

Tags: php, javascript, парсер

Добрый день. Как реализовать парсер на языке php, чтобы получить контент с сайта, который отдается js. И далее его didom разобрать.

Comment: Простите, но какой ответ вы ожидаете? Что за вас кто-то парсер напишет? Или что вам готовый парсер под любой сайт предоставят? Обращайтесь на биржи фрилансеров, вам там смогут помочь, но за деньги.

Comment: Я спросил, какими средствами, библиотекой. Мне готовый не нужен. Мне надо знать чем пользуются. PhantomJs , Selenium  и до.

Comment: Грабберы, обычно, индивидуальны. Анализируйте структуру, ищите как подсасывается информация и собирайте. Хотя грабберы - плохо, договоритесь о API с владельцем.

Comment: @АлександрМефистофель Selenium пользуется браузером точнее драйвером, а драйвер браузером и selenium не занимается ни каким парсингом!

Comment: Selenium некоторые используют для парсинг

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите получить конечную страницу с отработавшим на ней JS, используйте PhantomJS.

Но для начала, дерните ее curl'ом и посмотрите содержимое. Возможно нужные вам данные на ней есть в виде, например, JSON, а скрипт просто выстраивает на их основе страницу.
Таким образом, например, поступает Steam с комментариями. Конечная страница (с очень большим кол-вом комментариев) весит в несколько раз больше чем исходная с упаковаными в JSON данными.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вероятность что у сайты написанных на js есть версия для поисковых ботов, попробуйте отправить запрос с user-agent типа googlebot